# Sumifs function: How to add an entire block of data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

Is there a way to sumifs and the value in column E? I used the following function:

```
=SUMIFS(E3:H8,C3:C8,C11,D3:D8,D11)
```

Without creating a total column in I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($E$3:$H$8*($C$3:$C$8=C11)*($D$3:$D$8=D11))
```